# How to search for folders, avoiding the error "BaseRef is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated"?

Tags: xml, soap, netsuite

Making the following request to NetSuite web services:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope ...>
    <soap:Header>
        <platformMsgs:tokenPassport ...>
            ...
        </platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <platformMsgs:get>
            <platformMsgs:search>
                <searchRecord xsi:type="FolderSearch"/>
            </platformMsgs:search>
        </platformMsgs:get>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Returns an xml response with the **faultcode**: *soapenv:Server.userException*, and **faultstring**:

> rg.xml.sax.SAXException: {urn:core_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}BaseRef is an abstract type and cannot be instantiated

What does this error message mean? And what's the correct xml structure for the request?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had the "search" operation element inside a "get" operation. I was able to get the response I was expecting by changing the request xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope ...>
    <soap:Header>
        <platformMsgs:tokenPassport ...>
          ...
        </platformMsgs:tokenPassport>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <platformMsgs:search>
            <platformMsgs:search xsi:type="FolderSearch" xmlns="urn:filecabinet_2017_2.documents.webservices.netsuite.com" />
        </platformMsgs:search>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Not sure if this is the best syntax for the xml, but it works. Still not sure what the "BaseRef" was referring to.